# Can wordpress hold 100+K posts?

Tags: wordpress

I have a project of site niche , I have to do more than 100,000 posts, I find that wordpress is the best tool for my project but I read that it's not for big posts site
and i don't know the reason!!
so if i use wordpress for 100,000 posts site , what is the problem in the future may be happened
thanks

Comment: It is not a problem of the size of posts. As wordpress normally uses a MySQL database in the backend, these databases are designed to hold millions of entries. So scalability for the posts should not be a concern. The time for a single query for 1k or 1m entries in a table is nearly equal. The performance will dramatically decrease with concurrent users accessing the site, but that's not really wordpress related, but a general problem with cheaply hosted PHP sites.

Comment: nice tutorial about slow database performance: https://foliovision.com/2012/01/wordpress-performance-tips-big-sites